# Clicked a shortened link in a phishing email in Mac

Tags: macos, phishing

Today, I got a fake email that says it's from Amazon and I clicked a shortened url link in that email in both Google Chrome and Firefox. I noticed that the url it redirected to was not of Amazon's, so I immediately realized that I was phished, so I didn't enter any info.

I was on a Mac that runs Yosemite version 10.10.5 and I haven't updated Google Chrome for like one or two years. Firewall was on. I use Google Chrome to do all the money related activities.

After that, I deleted cookies and cache from Google Chrome and accessed my Amazon account through the real Amazon login page. It didn't seem anything has happened on my account yet.

I don't have any anti-virus software running on that Mac.

Is there any chance that my Mac is now in danger because of this? Should I do things like changing my Amazon password or re-installing the OS?

Comment: The outdated browser is bad, but in this case chances are you're fine. Windows is quite vulnerable to drive-by downloads requiring no further interaction, Mac has had relatively few cases. It sounds like the page was just a login phish and it's somewhat unlikely it did other malicious stuff. Seems like you caught it in time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a chance your mac is infected.  Without an analysis of the link you clicked on and your system, there's no way to know for sure.

That said, it's unlikely. If it was attempting to steal your credentials, it probably wasn't trying to drop malware, and even then it would likely be Windows malware.

Regardless, changing your password is probably a good idea. Reinstalling your OS is probably overkill. If you're really paranoid, you could run a wireshark capture on your system and look for indicators of C2 communication.

At the end of the day, it's your decision.